# Запятая после слова «который»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

*В мире есть мастера-виртуозы, **которые,** артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композицией, создают великолепные полотна.*

Объясните, почему в предложении после слова "который" стоит запятая.

Comment: Пожалуйста. уточняйте, что именно вас затрудняет при выборе запятых, как вы сами решали эту проблему.  Тогда вы получите более качественный ответ. Иначе ваш вопрос может рассматриваться как домашнее задание (ДЗ), а мы не решаем ДЗ.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ прост: *артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композицией* — это деепричастный оборот, который в данном случае требует обособления запятыми. От союзных слов и союзов (кроме *а*), как правило, отделяется запятой

Comment: Простой ответ, корректный и полный,  уже дан, зачем же повторяться (нет новой информации)? Такие ответы, как ваш,  могут и минусовать. Потом обсуждалась стилистика. По стилистике можете что-нибудь добавить?

Answer (score 1):

**Владе́я** — это деепричастие (что делая?) от *владеть*; *артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композицией* — деепричастный оборот.

Почему нужна запятая?
Такая ситуация доходчиво объяснена в ПАС под редакцией Лопатина:

> Деепричастный оборот, находящийся после союза или союзного слова, отделяется от него запятой (союзы не включаются в деепричастный оборот): *Он улыбнулся отцу и, сойдя вниз на палубу, подошел к одному матросу, который, **сидя на полу**, раскручивал кусок каната* (М. Г.)...

Такой оборот можно переставить в другое место предложения:
В мире есть мастера-виртуозы, которые создают великолепные полотна, артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композицией.

Вот похожие примеры:

*Но — чудес не бывает, и это — естественный результат работы людей, **которые, владея комплексным — всесторонним — знанием прошлого,** понимая все явления настоящего, точно и ясно определив цели будущего, смело принялись за работу, реализацию указаний истории* (М. Горький. Две пятилетки).

*В период с 1356 по 1372 год к Ганзе примкнуло около семидесяти городов Северной Европы, включая Таллин, Ригу, Гданьск и «Господина Великий Новгород», **который, владея ключом главных торговых путей, идущих с востока и юга,** получил на европейских рынках особенно важное значение* (Л. Н. Скрягин. Книга о якорях).

[Знаки препинания при обособленных обстоятельствах](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=121#pp121)

Answer (score 0):

Заданное предложение — это **не очень удачная переделка** другого:

*В мире не счесть мастеров-виртуОзов, // артистично владеющих рисунком, живописью, композицией и создающих великолепные полОтна.*

https://exams24.ru/v-mire-ne-schest-masterov-virtuozov-artistichno-vladeyushhih-risunkom-ege/

Почему **НЕУДАЧНАЯ**? Причастный оборот здесь намного уместнее по стилистике и произношению. Дело еще в том, что запятая после "которые" перед деепричастным оборотом чисто **грамматическая**, **паузы там нет.** Отсюда и вопросы о запятой...

**Как это **ПРОЧИТАТЬ**:** В мире есть мастера-виртуОзы, // котОрые, // артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композИцией, // создают великолепные полотна. А если прочитать с паузами нельзя, то **зачем писать с "паузами-запятыми"?** Куда как лучше использовать причастный оборот! Там никаких проблем, и фраза **короче, логичнее, красивее.**

Такие конструкции с союзным словом "которые" в принципе возможны для тех случаев, когда причастный оборот по каким-то причинам нельзя использовать.

**Еще вариант** записи без "которые": *В мире не счесть / мастеров-виртуОзов. Артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композИцией, они создают великолепные полОтна.*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

[Розенталь §211. Причастные обороты](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm)

Пункт 7. Причастные обороты используются для замены синонимичных придаточных определительных предложений в ряде случаев...

Comment: Удивительно, как люди любят фантазировать... Это никаким образом не моя правка, а предложение-аналог я нашла в Интернете. В то же время использование придаточного предложении с деепричастным оборотом сразу вызвало сомнения. Это параллельные конструкции, их всегда желательно сравнивать.

Answer (score 0):

**Как надо отвечать на этот вопрос** (мое мнение)

Наверное, **очень просто?** Тогда и ответ будет **лучшим?** Но нет, не это главное...

Вот что я хочу сказать по теме.

(1) Мы любим чувствовать свою  значимость и отвечать **на простые вопросы** вроде этого: почему обособляется деепричастный оборот? Нам приятно осознавать, что мы это знаем, а кто-то нет.

(2) Но мне почему-то кажется, что автор вопроса это тоже знает. А тогда **зачем** он спрашивает?

(3) Возможно, ему кое-что известно **о непростых отношениях** деепричастного оборота и слова «которые», как в таком, например, предложении: *Рынок подчиняется определенным законам, **зная которые** можно увеличить свои шансы на успех.*

Здесь «которые» входит в состав деепричастного оборота и не выделяется никакими знаками, что можно определить **на слух.**

(4) В заданном предложении тоже есть деепричастный оборот, союзное  слово «которые», а паузы нет. **Так нужна ли там запятая?**

Соответственно, в ответе нужно это обязательно отметить и объяснить **отсутствие паузы**, а вот это уже не так просто сделать. **Так почему там нет паузы?**

(5) Но мы не особенно внимательны к нашим авторам, поэтому видим только **внешнюю** (простую) сторону вопроса, а **не его суть.**

Answer (score 0):

**Дополнительный ответ на дополнительный вопрос**

*Скажите тогда, а почему стоит запятая перед словом "который"? И где в этом предложении, по вашему, грамматическая основа?*

В мире **есть мастера-виртуозы** [какие?], **которые**, артистично владея рисунком, живописью и композицией, **создают** великолепные полотна.

Это сложноподчиненное предложение с **придаточным определительным**.

• Придаточные определительные отвечают на вопросы определения: *какой? чей?* (здесь — *какие?*);
• относятся к члену в главном предложении, выраженному *существительным* (здесь — *мастера-виртуозы*), и всегда стоят после него;
• прикрепляются к главному при помощи союзных слов *который, какой, чей, кто, что, где, куда, откуда, когда* (здесь — *которые*).

Грамматические основы: *мастера-виртуозы есть, которые создают.*
Перед придаточным предложением (перед словом *который*) ставится запятая.

[Придаточные определительные](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/737-221_pridatochnye_opredelitelnye.html)
[Запятая между главной и придаточной частями сложноподчиненного предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=137#pp137)

Comment: А это не он задавал, а другой Федор. Их тут много. Тот вопрос уже убрали.

Comment: Я думаю, что это *тот же Федор*. Просто новый участник не понял, что дополнительные вопросы можно задавать в комментариях.

Comment: Один зарегистрированный, а другой нет.  Два в одном.